# 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: apache, load-balancing, moodle, centos7

i have 2 Apache servers and 2 Loadbalance servers and one File server(centos 7)and i am using maria db cluster.

i want to download som file from students i face a problem with this error:
504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.

i didn't find timeout in Httpd.conf.

i have changed  my php.ini :   max_execution_time = 1330000
And in my Loadbalancer the set up for haproxy.cfg  is:

contimeout 5000

```
clitimeout 50000
srvtimeout 50000
```

Many Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

first of all, If you haven't yet, make sure both max_execution_time and max_input_time in your php.ini file are set to a sufficient number of seconds. For example:

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
```

Secondly, Open up `httpd.conf` and look for the setting Timeout. If it doesn't exist, add it on its own line and set it to a sufficient number of seconds. For example:

```
Timeout 600
```

And finally, If you're experiencing the timeout in PHPMyAdmin, keep in mind that it has its own execution time limit, `ExecTimeLimit`. Open up config.inc.php and if it doesn't exist, add a config option with a sufficient number of seconds like this:

```php
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;
```